# Union and Intersection for List of Objects in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

List of Object 1

```
public class ActiveType {
    protected String serviceCategoryCode;
    protected String serviceOcc;
    protected String serviceCode;
    protected String to;
    protected String free;
}
```

List of Object 2

```
public class PendingType {
    protected String worNumber;
    protected String serviceCode;
    protected String serviceOcc;
    protected String from;
    protected String to;
}
```

Having two list of objects.

```
1. List<ActiveType>
2. List<PendingType>
```

I had to create a new list, if service code of the two list matches.
And another list with remaining objects from both(ActiveTpe + PendingType) the list.

How can we achieve union and intersection for list of object in java ?

Comment: cannot you implement it using Sets?

Comment: What do you mean by "create a new list, if service code of the two list matches"; could you clarify this requirement?

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic : if the servicecode of ActiveType and Pending Type is equal , add that object to the new list.

Comment: @hermit : I can convert this List to set

Comment: Override equals() and hashCode() methods to compare based on serviceCode, then you can use Sets

Comment: Please note that unless `ActiveType` and `PendingType` can have a common super type (class or interface), the "union" list will have to be a raw list (`List<Object>`), which means you have to cast the objects upon retrieval (and that's not so nice).

Comment: Can I have a code sample for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use contains(Object o). Iterate through the list and if the current object is contained in the second list then save it in a third list called intersection list. After you have done the intersection you can do the union by removing with remove(Object o) all the objects from both initial lists which are in the intersection list. Then simply create a new list with the elements of the intersection list and what left of the initial lists and you will have the union. Also you might want to save the initial lists if you still need them later.

Apply contains to the current element of your list. If you have list1, list 2 and a new empty list3 then :

```
 for (Object x:list1)
     if (list2.contains(x))
          list3.add(x);
```

Once the for loop is done list3 will have all the elements obtained from the intersection of list1 and list2.

Comment: contains() will applied to member variable(service code)?

Comment: this also is based on `equals()` that asks about service code

Answer (score 0):

if `ActiveType` and `PendingType` can share a super class with shared properties like this:

```
public class SuperType {
    protected String serviceCode;
    protected String serviceOcc;
}
```

then creating and populating a `Set<? extends SuperType>` will produce the intersection. of course, `SuperType`'s `equals()` wil have to be based on `serviceCode`

Comment: No I can't create a super class here.

Comment: then what do you expect the type of the intersection collection to be? without a common super type, it can only be `List<Object>`

Comment: It should be a new List : List<OtherType>, Do I need to iterate through each list and identify ?

Comment: what is OtherType ?? anyway, there is no way to compare different types in Java other then iterating on each item and searching ( and its o(n^2)) and you  have to instantiate OtherType instances as well.

Comment: Can I use Set in this case ?

Comment: why dont you try and tell us